# Realm object list functions are undefined, even though object is defined and list is populated

Tags: javascript, node.js, realm, realm-list, realm-js

Trying to push a new int into an int realm list. I can get the Realm object, I can print it and when I print the object it shows the list with it's content, I can use Realm Studio to edit, add numbers to the list, etc.. But when I try to call any methods form the list it says it is undefined.

Have tried async, await, then, though it was a synchronization issue, but doesn't seem like it.

The code below is similar to mine, but edited to hide the original names, etc, and does not have all the properties from the original, but it does not change the behave for the specific list I am trying to edit. Everything else works fine.
I have an schema like

```
let mySchema={
    name:'MySchema',
    properties:{
        my_schema_id: 'string',
        numbers: 'int[]'
    }
```

The function to create a new object is

```
Realm.open({schema: [mySchema]})
  .then(realm => {
    realm.write(() => {

        realm.create('MySchema', {my_schema_id: `${my_schema_id}`, numbers: [parseInt(number, 10)]});
      });
```

I try to add a number with:

```
Realm.open({schema: [mySchema]})
    .then((realm) => {
    let fetchedSchema = realm.objects('MySchema').filtered(`my_schema_id ="${my_schema_id}"`);

console.log(fetchedSchema);
    realm.write(()=>{
        fetchedSchema.numbers.push(parseInt(number, 10));
    });
```

And it gives an error:

```
(node:73249) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I expected to push the item to the list, or to be able to call the list functions. Instead, when I try to use the list it shows as `undefined` even though I can see it and it's content when I print the object...

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. 
Querying `let fetchedSchema = realm.objects('MySchema').filtered(`my_schema_id ="${my_schema_id}"`);` actually returns an array of elements, so I just had to select the first with `[0]`at the end